# Linux alternative for FreeBSD systat tool

Tags: linux, monitoring, freebsd, command-line-interface

I'm looking for a Linux alternative for [systat](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/FreeBSD/man1/systat.1.html) tool that is avalaible only for FreeBSD.

What do you recommend?

Comment: There's a very similar question in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127371/is-there-an-equivalent-to-systat-in-linux with different answers...

Comment: [nmon](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nmon/) might be worth a look?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Linux Sysstat**: [http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/documentation.html](http://pagesperso-orange.fr/sebastien.godard/)

Try google with "***linux sysstat***" keywords

Answer (score 3):

I am also quite fond of [`dstat`](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/dstat/).